# SQL stored procedure returning few rows as errors

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, datatable

I am trying to return all the rows in a table using SQL stored procedure. The result is then stored in a DataTable using C#.

On executing the stored procedure through EXEC command am getting the result as expected in SQL environment. But when the values are being stored in the DataTable, few rows are just showing errors while others showing some data.

The stored procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE procDDSDDAReg (@v_querytype VARCHAR(20), @v_Itemindex  INT)
AS 
BEGIN
 IF @v_querytype = 'SELECT_REQUEST'
  BEGIN 
        SELECT * FROM  DDSInternetBankingDDADetails o
        WHERE isnull(o.uploadstatus,'N') = 'N' AND o.InstructionCode='RQST';
  END; 
ELSE IF  @v_querytype = 'UPDATE' 
  BEGIN
   UPDATE DDSInternetBankingDDADetails SET uploadstatus ='Y' WHERE  Itemindex=@v_Itemindex 
  END; 
  

ELSE IF  @v_querytype = 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK' 
  BEGIN
   UPDATE DDSInternetBankingDDADetails SET uploadstatus ='N' WHERE  Itemindex=@v_Itemindex 
  END; 
   
 END;
GO
```

The snapshot of the DataTable is:
[image]

The snapshot of C# code is:
[image]

Although no error is being thrown. Please let me know the possible reason for it.

Comment: Your database is has some restrictions that your sql table doesn't. perhaps a unique constraint or non-nullable column that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Please tag dbms product used!

Comment: It is SqlDbx Version 3.60 (Personal Edition)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I did not get you. Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: How is your c# DataTable created?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, please find the code:
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

string sResult = Webservice.ExecuteDBOperation(sQuery, sQueryType, udtDBParameter, ref dt);

I called a WebService that connects with the database and fetches it and then stores it in the DataTable. Please see the that 'dt' variable is of ref type. If the operation was successful then sResult has value SUCCESS else FAIL.

Comment: What does ExecuteDBOperation do? does it add columns to the data table?

Comment: Yes, just add columns and rows to the data table.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  (Don't trust the Dataset Visualizer in VS2008)

Comment: @Stan - Yes it is VS2008. And yes you are right. I will never trust DataSet visualizer now onward. Even though the DataSet shows the errors in row, the Quickwatch over the rows and column properties shows the actual values in all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Unbelievably, this is a bug in the VS2008 Data Visualizer.

`Quickwatch` over the rows and column properties shows the actual values in all rows, but is obviously much more tedious to use.

Comment: Yes, in fact I struggled for hours to resolve this error thinking that later an exception would be thrown. But when I found no solution over web I continued execution and was surprised to find out that Rows and Columns property were showing the obvious value and the program continued without any exception thrown.